# DataImport in SOLR

Tags: database, search, solr, dataimporthandler

As I understand during data import into SOLR, all data is erased and a new one is added.

At the moment I have data that contains 4 fields. After importing from the SQL database(data contains 3 fields), new data is created that contains 3 fields.

Is it possible **not to overwrite data** that has more fields when importing or some way to save the fourth field?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can do the partial update and save the 4th field of the document..Use set – set or replace a particular value, or remove the value if null is specified as the new value

Comment: but if you want the data to be updated using DIH only...then its not possible

Comment: For partial updates, take a look at the documentation for "atomic updates" https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html